# MySQL, Why Does This Simple 'CREATE TABLE' Query Fail?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

A very simple query.

```
CREATE TABLE Group
(
    Group_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Group_Name varchar(128)
);
```

Unfortunately, it will not execute, see error below in PhpMyAdmin.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1isvB.png)

I have checked and checked again, it seems to be syntactically correct, but never will complete.

Comment: `Group` is a reserved word.  Either choose a different name or use backticks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Group` is a *[reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)* to use it as table name you need to escape it.

Use `Back-ticks` to escape the reserved Keywords

```
CREATE TABLE `Group`
(
    Group_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Group_Name varchar(128)
);
```

Comment: Now it all makes sense, thanks!